# PHP Erode Image - NOT IMAGEMAGICK

Tags: php, image, filter

Is here any `ERODE` (name from Paint Shop Pro) filter implementation in PHP/GDLIB? I was trying to find one, but no luck... in fact even ImageMagick doesn't have that filter...

I mean filter that converts this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

**Other example to show that `blur` is not the same**

[image]

**Please note**, that those are not manually generated images - they are live examples of `ERODE` filter in `Paint Shop Pro 9`

Comment: It is just blurring the image. Imagik does have that: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.blurimage.php

Comment: It is not. Check question edit.

Comment: According to the filter description, erode works per pixel. The luminosity of the pixel is increased to the maximum luminosity of every neighboring pixel. However, your example appears to do the opposite. The luminosity of every pixel is lowered to the minimum luminosity of every neighboring pixel. If you want to do that, it isn't a terribly complicated function to write in PHP.

Comment: what? I wouldn't say that it lowers some luminosity... eroded P seems to be much darker... PS. As I said, I use Paint Shop Pro to generate those examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had not seen this function until this question. I don't see it in ImageMagick (and it certainly is not a built-in PHP function). I liked what it did, so I wrote a couple functions that produce the same effect. This only works in a one-pixel radius. I have tried to write this as verbose as possible to make it easy for someone else to customize the code to his/her needs.

```
// Takes an image, (x,y) coordinate, and returns the luminosity
function imageluminosity(&$img, $x, $y)
{
    $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8 ) 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    // These values are based on standard pixel brightness per color.
    // 0.299+0.587+0.114 = 1
    return 0.299*$r + 0.587*$g + 0.114*$b;
}

// Degrades an image by enhancing the darker areas of the image.
// Does not alter the original image.
// Returns an eroded image.
// This works on EVERY pixel, so it takes a looooong time.
function imagedegrade(&$oimg)
{
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($oimg), imagesy($oimg));
    for($x=0; $x<imagesx($oimg); $x++)
    {
        for($y=0; $y<imagesy($oimg); $y++)
        {
            //Find the most luminosity in any neighboring pixel
            $olum = $blum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x, $y);
            if($x>0)
            {
                if($y>0)
                {
                    $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x-1, $y-1);
                    if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
                }
                $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x-1, $y);
                if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
                if($y<imagesy($oimg)-1)
                {
                    $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x-1, $y+1);
                    if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
                }
            }
            if($y>0)
            {
                $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x1, $y-1);
                if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
            }
            if($y<imagesy($oimg)-1)
            {
                $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x1, $y+1);
                if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
            }
            if($x<imagesx($oimg)-1)
            {
                if($y>0)
                {
                    $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x+1, $y-1);
                    if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
                }
                $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x+1, $y);
                if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
                if($y<imagesy($oimg)-1)
                {
                    $tlum = imageluminosity($oimg, $x+1, $y+1);
                    if($tlum > $lum) $blum = $tlum;
                }
            }
            // Get RGB from original image
            $color = imagecolorat($oimg, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            // Adjust luminosity to best luminosity of any neighboring pixel.
            if($olum != $blum)
            {
                $diff = $olum - $blum;
                $r = min(255, max(0, round($r + $diff * 0.299)));
                $g = min(255, max(0, round($g + $diff * 0.587)));
                $b = min(255, max(0, round($b + $diff * 0.114)));
            }
            // Get or allocate new color.
            $color = imagecolorexact($img, $r, $g, $b);
            if($color == -1)
                $color = imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);
            imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $color);
        }
    }
    return $img;
}
```

I hope I didn't make any typos. The function I use is MUCH less verbose, but very cryptic.